# lxml.parse always gives a wrong result on macOS

Tags: python, python-requests, lxml

I'm trying to fetch an HTML source from a website using `requests` module and then parse it using `lxml` module.

When I try to parse the HTML source, it always gives a wrong result. However, when I first write the source into a text file and then try to parse the file, a correct result is given.

**Source**

```py
import io
import lxml.html
import requests

css_selector: str = '#add-to-cart-button'

url: str = 'https://www.amazon.co.jp/LuaniJP-Luani-%E3%82%A4%E3%83%A4%E3%83%9B%E3%83%B3%E7%B7%A8%E7%B5%84%E9%85%8D%E7%B7%9A%E8%B6%85%E4%BD%8E%E9%9F%B3%E3%81%A7%E8%80%B3%E9%9F%B3%E6%A5%BD%E3%82%A4%E3%83%A4%E3%83%9B%E3%83%B3%E3%83%8F%E3%82%A4%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86%E3%83%AC%E3%82%AA%E3%82%A4%E3%83%A4%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%8E%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BA%E5%88%86%E9%9B%A2%E3%82%B9%E3%83%9D%E3%83%BC%E3%83%84%E3%82%A4%E3%83%A4%E3%83%9B%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9E%E3%82%A4%E3%82%AF%E4%BB%98%E3%81%8D/dp/B083J4HYYY/ref=sr_1_5?__mk_ja_JP=%E3%82%AB%E3%82%BF%E3%82%AB%E3%83%8A&dchild=1&keywords=bluetooth+%E3%82%A4%E3%83%A4%E3%83%9B%E3%83%B3&qid=1619161477&sr=8-5'

file:           str    = '.tmp'
in_memory_file: object = None

html_source: str = requests.get(url, headers = {'User-Agent': '', "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5"}).text
with open(file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(html_source)
in_memory_file = io.StringIO(html_source)

e1: object = lxml.html.fromstring(html_source)
e2: object = lxml.html.parse(file).getroot()
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    e3: object = lxml.html.parse(f).getroot()
e4: object = lxml.html.parse(in_memory_file).getroot()

for e in (e1, e2, e3, e4):
    try:
        print(e.body.text_content()[:100])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

**Expected Output**

All of the four lines shall be exactly the same since the HTML source of `e1`, `e2`, `e3` and `e4` are the same.

```
{"AUI_MM_DESKTOP_LAUNCH_291918":"C","AUI_TNR_V2_180836":"C","AUI_PRELOAD_261698":"C","AUI_CSA_TEMPLA
{"AUI_MM_DESKTOP_LAUNCH_291918":"C","AUI_TNR_V2_180836":"C","AUI_PRELOAD_261698":"C","AUI_CSA_TEMPLA
{"AUI_MM_DESKTOP_LAUNCH_291918":"C","AUI_TNR_V2_180836":"C","AUI_PRELOAD_261698":"C","AUI_CSA_TEMPLA
{"AUI_MM_DESKTOP_LAUNCH_291918":"C","AUI_TNR_V2_180836":"C","AUI_PRELOAD_261698":"C","AUI_CSA_TEMPLA
```

**Actual Output**

`e1` and `e4` give wrong results.

```
!   d   o   c   t   y   p   e       h   t   m   l   >   
{"AUI_MM_DESKTOP_LAUNCH_291918":"C","AUI_TNR_V2_180836":"C","AUI_PRELOAD_261698":"C","AUI_CSA_TEMPLA
{"AUI_MM_DESKTOP_LAUNCH_291918":"C","AUI_TNR_V2_180836":"C","AUI_PRELOAD_261698":"C","AUI_CSA_TEMPLA
!   d   o   c   t   y   p   e       h   t   m   l   >
```

Is this a bug?

---

**Environments**

- macOS Big Sur
- Python 3.9.4
- lxml 4.6.3
- requests 2.25.1

(When I execute the script above on Arch Linux server, the expected result is given. The versions of `lxml` and `requests` are the same whilst `Python 3.9.1` is used.)

---

**Edit 1**

Here is the response header printed by `requests.get(...).headers`.

```
{
    'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=UTF-8',
    'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Server': 'Server',
    'Date': 'Sun, 25 Apr 2021 11:48:29 GMT',
    'x-amz-rid': '8KTM6B57AG2Y9YFRSW81',
    'set-cookie': 'session-id=358-2447187-0599056; Domain=.amazon.co.jp; Expires=Mon, 25-Apr-2022 11:48:29 GMT; Path=/; Secure, session-id-time=2082787201l; Domain=.amazon.co.jp; Expires=Mon, 25-Apr-2022 11:48:29 GMT; Path=/; Secure, i18n-prefs=JPY; Domain=.amazon.co.jp; Expires=Mon, 25-Apr-2022 11:48:29 GMT; Path=/',
    'Accept-CH-Lifetime': '86400',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-transform',
    'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff',
    'X-XSS-Protection': '1;',
    'Accept-CH': 'ect,rtt,downlink',
    'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
    'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=47474747; includeSubDomains; preload',
    'Vary': 'Content-Type,X-Amazon-Wtm-Tag-SP-Detail-Secured-Port-Enabled,Accept-Encoding,X-Amzn-CDN-Cache,X-Amzn-AX-Treatment,User-Agent',
    'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
    'X-Cache': 'Miss from cloudfront',
    'Via': '1.1 ae4c25c7fdaa0729468f3f918223a587.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)',
    'X-Amz-Cf-Pop': 'NRT12-C5',
    'X-Amz-Cf-Id': 'LFiPqzjuK3JzlbqhNORxQ8fpmiB_NfwUVvhTOHrVoBvVjWlGHLHrNA=='
}
```

---

**Edit 2**

I checked the `<meta>` tags using the command

```sh
$ grep --only-matching '<meta[^>]\+>' HTML_SOURCE_FILE
```

and the result is this:

```html
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv='x-dns-prefetch-control' content='on'>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=Shift_JIS" />
<meta name="description" content="Amazon.co.jp： Luani イヤホン編組配線超低音で耳音楽イヤホンハイファイステレオイヤフォンノイズ分離スポーツイヤホンマイク付き: 家電・カメラ" />
<meta name="title" content="Amazon.co.jp： Luani イヤホン編組配線超低音で耳音楽イヤホンハイファイステレオイヤフォンノイズ分離スポーツイヤホンマイク付き: 家電・カメラ" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Luani イヤホン編組配線超低音で耳音楽イヤホンハイファイステレオイヤフォンノイズ分離スポーツイヤホンマイク付き,LuaniJP" />
```

Comment: **a)** Can you include the response headers, especially the `Content-Type` header? **b)** When you stream the HTTP response directly to file like `r = requests.get(url, stream=True)` and then `with open(file, 'wb') as f: for chunk in r: f.write(chunk)` (note the file is `'wb'`, not `'w'`!) - what does that file look like afterwards?

Comment: @Tomalak Thank you for you suggestion. (a) Nothing changed. (b) In that case, the correct result is given.

Comment: how is "nothing changed" an answer to *"Can you include the response headers, especially the Content-Type header?"*? Could you please show the response headers for this request in your question?

Comment: @Tomalak Sorry I misread your comment. Please see the edit.

Comment: Ok so the response is designated to be `charset=UTF-8`. When you open the streamed file from above, what does the text editor say about its encoding? Same thing?

Comment: @Tomalak `vim` says `encoding=utf-8`.

Comment: And it looks correct in vim? In that case, when you use a regular (i.e. non-streamed) request and `lxml.html.fromstring(r.text)`, it should come out just fine (no need for `StringIO` here...). If you write the `r.text` to file and use `lxml.html.parse(file)`, it should also be fine, but make sure that you specify `encoding='utf8'` for both `open()` calls. (As a general rule, you should never use `open()` on text files without specifying the `encoding` parameter.)

Comment: @Tomalak Yes, it looks correct. Very strange...

Comment: I'm confused, if all these things I described are working, what's the issue again now?

Comment: @Tomalak I agree with your first *it should come out just fine* but actually it doesn't work like so (as described in OP). Directly feeding `r.text` gives a wrong result.

Comment: If you print the text to the console or write it to file and both of these outputs look correct, `lxml.html.fromstring(r.text)` **must** be correct, too. There is no way it cannot be.

Comment: ...wait, is there a `<meta encoding="...">` tag in the HTML source?

Comment: @Tomalak Yes. I do agree with you. This is the very reason why I posted this question. As for `<meta>`, please see the edit.

Comment: I think the `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=Shift_JIS" />` might be a problem. Can you try to remove that before parsing the string? (The `<meta charset="utf-8"/>`, too, while you're at it.)

Comment: @Tomalak I inserted `html_source = html_source.replace('<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=Shift_JIS" />', '')` or `html_source = html_source.replace('<meta charset="utf-8"/>', '')` before parsing. The former didn't change the result at all. The latter didn't change the results for `e1` and `e4` while `e2` and `e3` says `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 0: invalid start byte`.

Comment: Well, I'm stumped. I can't reproduce the issue on my end, and I've explored everything I could think of on yours. Sorry. :-/

Comment: @Tomalak Thank you VERY much for your kind advices and suggestions :)

Comment: You said you removed `'<meta charset="utf-8"/>'` and then it started giving you "invalid start byte" errors? I'm quite sure that this is impossible. *How* were you parsing? I was talking about `lxml.html.fromstring(html_source)`, where `html_source` is a string that looks OK when printed to the console. `fromstring()` *cannot* produce "invalid start byte" errors, because it never tries to convert bytes to string. The only point where "invalid start byte" errors can occur is when you do `lxml.html.parse(file)`.

Comment: @Tomalak The ways of parsing are as posted in the OP. In the previous comment, I said "*`e2` and `e3` says...*" and I use `parse()` to create `e2` and `e3`. My final purpose: I'd like to somehow make `e1` give the correct result.

Comment: After fixing the *one* obvious mistake in your code - not specifying a file encoding when opening text files - your code runs without issues in my setup (Win10, Python 3.7, requests 2.25.1, lxml 4.6.2). All my comments above center around testing the hypothesis that somewhere there is a  hidden encoding issue, something like a different default between your environment and mine. I suppose the only way for you to gain more insight is trying out different versions of Python and the various libraries to see which combination triggers it, because there's nothing else wrong with the code per se.